# Dimension selection based on test accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, pca, model-selection

consider that I have a dataset with train, validation and test set and I want to train the pipeline PCA+logistic regression classifier. So far, for a specific k (that is the reduced data dimension from PCA), a logistic regression classifier is trained on the training set, using the validation set for tuning the parameters of the classifier. The fine-tuned classifier is subsequently used to get an accuracy for the test data. Then, for another value of k, the same procedure is followed to get another accuracy for the test data.

Is it fair to follow this procedure to choose the best value for k?

Comment: This method is OK for selecting the best model, but the test error you get will be biased low because you did optimization over the test set. You will need yet another holdout set to get a proper test error with this method.

Answer (score 2):

No, this procedure isn't fair because you're essentially fitting your $k$ (number of principal components) to the test set. This results in information leakage from the test set and therefore means you'll get a biased estimate of how well your model will generalise to unseen data.

You should think of $k$ as another hyperparameter that you're tuning, so you should use the validation set for this purpose. I guess the key is to realise that you're basically *tuning a pipeline* ($k$ + logistic regression hyperparameters), so use the validation set to tune it and then use the test set to get an idea of how well your *best model* will generalise.